# Display the value in textbox based on the change of dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that has a dropdown and on change of the dropdown, i need to update the values in the corresponding text boxes but the value is not being displayed evn though the value is there. Please help

My code looks like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReportingAgencies, new SelectList(Model.ReportingAgencies, "SelectedAgency.AgencyGuid", "SelectedAgency.Name"), "--Select An Agency--", new { id = "dropDownReportAgencies" })
                </td>                 
            </tr>
            <tr class="seperator"></tr>
            <tr class="seperator"></tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Wages)</td> 
                <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Wages)</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Tax)</td> 
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Tax)</td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="rightButtonControls">        
            @if (Model.IsEditable)
            {
                <button id="btnSave" value="save">Save</button>                
            }
        </div>    
    </fieldset>
}

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { id = "CompanyId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { id = "EmployeeId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FilingYear, new { id = "FilingYear" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divLoader").css('display', 'none');
        $('#dropDownReportAgencies').change(function () {
            var selectedAgency = $('#dropDownReportAgencies option:selected').val();
            alert(selectedAgency);
            var CompanyId = $('#CompanyId').val();
            var EmployeeId = $('#EmployeeId').val();
            var FilingYear = $('#FilingYear').val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("W2State", "W2Generation")';
            $.get(url, { agencyId: selectedAgency, companyId: CompanyId, employeeId: EmployeeId, filingYear: FilingYear },
                function (data) {
                }                
                );
        });
    });
```

But the values are not being displayed in the text fields. Please help on this

Comment: which textboxes are you trying to update here?

Comment: the values aren't being displayed in *which* text fields? the only thing I see you doing with selectedAgency is alerting it, not setting anything to it.

Comment: <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Tax) is the display box where i am trying to populate the data from my view model

Comment: What does the W2State action return in the W2Generation controller?  Can you post that code also?

Comment: @RashmiKR did you get this figured out?

Comment: @ethorn10 Yes i got this figured out... function(data) is not returning anything.. Instead it had to return the html data. Such a small thing and it took me a while to figure out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to return html(data) instead of returning function(data)